# Yield in parent function in Python?

Tags: python, macros, yield

I have a music library in Python that involves a system of clocks. Currently, they are implemented with different threads that use Events and Locks, etc. to keep everything synchronized. But the truth is, I want it to be effectively single-threaded.

The current syntax for the clocks is that you can fork functions like this:

```py
def some_musical_process():
    play_a_note()
    wait(2)
    play_another_note()
    wait(1.5)
    ...etc...

fork(some_musical_process)
```

When a function is forked, it is set up on its own thread. The wait function causes the execution of the process to stop and wait for a signal to wake up 2 beats later. The problem is, since each of these functions is a different thread, it's a bit of a nightmare to stop and start them at the right times.

It has always struck me that this is more suited to using generator functions; something along these lines:

```
import random
import time


def yielding_routine():
    while True:
        print("hello")
        yield random.choice([0.5, 1.0])



# Scheduler
yr = yielding_routine()
delay = next(yr)
while True:
    time.sleep(delay)
    delay = next(yr)
```

The problem is, I don't want to change the API. I want to keep that the user calls "wait", instead of yield, partly for backwards-compatibility, and also partly because there are several specialized wait functions like "wait_for_children_to_finish()" and stuff like that. What I really want is something like this:

```py
def yielding_routine():
    while True:
        print("hello")
        wait(random.choice([0.5, 1.0]))


def wait(dur):
    (((somehow cause the parent to yield dur)))
```

Where the `wait` function somehow yields in the parent generator function. Is there any way Python can do this? Even something hacky with "eval" or something? Effectively what I want is a macro, and I'm not sure if there are good ways to get that kind of functionality in Python.

Or is there an alternate approach that I haven't considered?

Many thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand correctly, but maybe you need a decorator?

Comment: Unless `yield` is *statically* present in the `def` statement, the statement produces an ordinary function, not a generator function.

Comment: You might want look at using coroutines using the `asyncio` module, which would require a *slight* change in the API.

Answer (score 0):

The music library that I built uses actual time to solve scheduling problems.  Here's my actual method that solves this problem for me:

```
def wait_for_the_future(target_time):
    """ If target_time is in future, sleep 'til then. """
    time_remaining = target_time - datetime.datetime.now()
    if time_remaining > datetime.timedelta(seconds=.000001):
        time.sleep(max(0, time_remaining.total_seconds() - .000001))
```

The hard part, if you take this approach, is the scheduling math to convert your musical events to moments in time.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the `asyncio` module to define a coroutine. This requires a few small changes to the syntax, but otherwise keeps your API the same.

```
import asyncio
from asyncio import sleep as wait


async def yielding_routine():
    while True:
        print("hello")
        await wait(random.choice([0.5, 1.0]))

yr = yielding_routine()

asyncio.run(yr)
```

You might also want to read more about the `asyncio` module to see how to work with the coroutines defined by `async def`.